# How to apply this effect to the last line of a text?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to set a custom `border` to a part of a text (as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hnyhbpm8/)) that will be applied only to the last line of the whole text.

In this case, only to `2000 years old.` (with that length of course; not `800px` which is the length of the parent `div`):

```
span
{
    color: #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:20px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:52px;
}
```

For the purpose I've add a `span`, but in a real text I don't have any delimiter. How would you do this in CSS?

Comment: I think you can not do it with CSS. If a leading breakline there, or a tag, then you can achive, but CSS has no property like last-line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `::after` along with `position:relative/absolute` for this:

```css
body {
  line-height: 40px;
}
div {
  width: 800px;
  font-size: 52px;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative
}

div::after {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  width: 315px;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div>
  Contrary to popular belief Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no selector for the last line of text.

As such we'd have to use some trickery to achieve this.

I'd suggest a bottom border which would then be overlayed for anything after the text with a pseudo-element.

Restrictions:

1. The element needs `overflow:hidden`,
2. The background of the pseudo-element has to be set manually.

This will effectively underline the last line of text regardless of how long it is without setting the width of the pseudo-element to anything other than a really big number.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnyhbpm8/3/)

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
p::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2000px; /* any really large number */
  height: 1px; /* same height as border */
  background: white; /* to cover the border */
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Pity, but the background should be "transparent", since it is over an image for example.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution with `:before` and `:after`.

`:before` works as a border, while `:after` covers the rest of the line. This way it is also possible to set a transition while hovering the element.

```css
ul{width: 180px}

li{
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}

a{
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

a:after{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2000px; /* any really large number */
  height: 1px; /* same height as border */
  background: white; /* to cover the border */
  top: 100%;
}

a:before{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px; /* same height as border */
  background: red; /* to cover the border */
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover > a:before{
    max-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  
  <li>
     <a href="#">Short link</a>
  </li>
  
  <li>
     <a href="#">This link  is longer and it goes to a new line </a>
  </li>
  
  <li>
     <a href="#">This link is longer as well and it also goes to a new line</a>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```